# Proof with conditional introduction

Tags: logic, proof

Below is a screen-cap of part of a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9cElQcKlE4&t=813s) where a proof using conditional introduction is shown, which is proving under certain assumptions that given A is true, then the adjacent sentence is also true.

I think I am misinterpreting the proof, as it would seem to be implying that under the assumption of B is true, and knowing A is true, then B implies A is true, but this can't be right. Surely B and A can both be true without B entailing A. **So how does the proof work?**

I'm really confused.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: If A is true, then any B, true or not, implies A in classical logic. Indeed, False → True and True → True are both true. [Material conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#Philosophical_problems_with_material_conditional) is not about anything affecting anything's existence, it is purely formal. You are probably thinking about something like relevance conditional, which requires relevance of conclusion to the premise, and is non-classical.

Comment: Perhaps, but formal logic does not care about meanings, only logical form. And in classical logic everything is decided by truth values, including implication. So False → True and True → True lead to A →  (B → A) being a tautology.

Comment: "If A is true, then any B, true or not, implies A". But if B is false and A is true, then wouldn't B → A be false?

Comment: If B is false and A is true then B → A is true. False → True and False → False, that's how the material conditional works: *ex falso quodlibet* - from falsehood, anything, see [explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).

Answer (score 1):

The OP raises the following question about the implication *A ∴ B → A*.

> I think I am misinterpreting the proof, as it would seem to be implying that under the assumption of B is true, and knowing A is true, then B implies A is true, but this can't be right. Surely B and A can both be true without B entailing A. **So how does the proof work?**

One way to see what is going on is to consider a truth table.  [Here is one](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/):

[image]

The fourth line in that table shows what happens to the implication when both *A* and *B* are true.

Another way is to try to write a proof oneself.  Here is one way to do this with a [proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) to make sure the steps are correct:

[image]

Here the reiteration (R) rule on line 3 allows us to copy *A* from line 1 to line 3. One can then rewrite lines 2 and 3 as a conditional using the rule of conditional introduction (→I).

What makes this work is a truth predicate that assigns a true or false value to each of the sentences symbolized as letters. Couple that with inference rules and one has a truth-functional logic. Follow the rules and trust the symbolization can be assigned a truth predicate and the logic flows without considering what it is one is talking about.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Stanford Truth Table Tool: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/

Answer (score 0):

> I think I am misinterpreting the proof, as it would seem to be implying that under the assumption of B is true, and knowing A is true, then B implies A is true, but this can't be right. Surely B and A can both be true without B entailing A. So how does the proof work?

When we are promised that something is true, then it will still be true under *any* assumption.

```
A, B, C, D |- A
```

When something is true under an assumption then we may *discharge* that assumption to deduce a conditional statement that holds under all other assumptions.

```
   A, C, D |- B → A
```

And so on.

```
      A, D |- C → (B → A)

         A |- D → (C → (B → A))

           |- A → (D → (C → (B → A)))
```